# "under maintenance" view in IIS, while stop / start .net core application

Tags: asp.net-core, iis

I want to display like an "under maintenance" page, while I restart (stop and then start) my IIS .net core website.

I want to do this, because I often need to replace some .dll's and I also want to tell the users, that the website is still active, just under construction for some minutes.

I need to stop the website, otherwise I'm not able to replace the .dll files.

Is there a good way to do this directly in IIS? Maybe also another nice way to do this, despite IIS?

Comment: You probably mean _under maintenance_ because _under construction implies that the site does not yet exist :)

Comment: Two things: 1) It's always a bad idea to hot swap DLLs. Publish a new version of your site if you've made changes. 2) It's better to upload to a different folder and then swap the site to the new folder. This will cause zero downtime *and* gives you a way to recover if something goes wrong (i.e. just swap back to the old working directory).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are maybe looking for *app_offline.html*

Placing this file into the root of the web app will cause stopping the app and serve that single file instead. I did use that with asp.net. First versions of asp.net core did not support it but meanwhile they should as the doc states.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-3.0#appofflinehtm